# How to look-for/find a specific string/selector/XPath across multiple web pages from the "inspect element" browser option?

Tags: html, search, browser, printing-web-page, inspect-element

I hope y'all having an amazing day.

As my question raised, 
how can I search/look/inspect for an element (in NOT just one page, but) in multiple web pages at once.

The purpose is to find a string (or a Code such "186.png") throughout the whole website without need to visit by myself every web page and inspect element every time.

I've tried to look for a solution that might lead me to print the whole website html sources and elements but, unfortunately, I have no such strong background in html.

Please Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, use the web scraper tool to inspect elements you want across multiple web pages. look for it from the web extensions store of your browser.